# Interceptor in Android

Tags: android

I have an Android app, which require to check authentication token every time perform action to call a web service, therefore I had to included the checking code snippet in all activities. I would like to ask whether an interceptor exist in Android platform, if yes, please share the best practice to apply the interceptor to my code? Thanks.

Comment: You can make unique method and put your interceptor code in it then call this method wherever you required. You don't have to re code every time in your activity

Comment: thank you, that's obviously right answer. I want to find an Interceptor but seem it is not supported in android

Answer (score 2):

Using run time reflection is not recommended for android, so you should not use any library which provides run time intercepting your HTTP request. You can write a simple HTTP request utility method and route all your HTTP requests through this method.

```
 public static void makePostRequest(String url, Object body, Context context, AsyncHttpResponseHandler handler) { // here you can add your authentication token to header}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have thought about this solution. Since Android does not support Interceptor as you said, so I think this is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you want to avoid multiple authentication checking. So, think about creating a custom class which will check for authentication token, then in all your activities, extend that class. For example:

```
public abstract class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Your authentication code goes here
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends MyActivity {
    // Your concrete class
}
```

This way, you can forget about putting authentication code everywhere.

Comment: If I do so, the app still check authentication even I don't call the WS